# Stuck in Grub recovery after Linux Mint install

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint, grub2

Every time I try to install Linux Mint XFCE my laptop freezes on removing the live packages, which happens just before the installation of GRUB2.

However: I've managed to manually install GRUB2. Problem is: there are no settings.

So when I boot the system I end up on the grub recovery console.

I did get my kernel semi-up and running with

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz...
initrd /boot/initrd...
boot
```

But then the kernel says there are some missing boot arguments and "target filesystem doesn't have required /sbin/init" ...

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would save yourself a lot of trouble by reinstalling freshly. If you had a desktop I'd say to use another hard drive to install mint, then mount your old one and get your stuff off of it. Seeing as you have a laptop, this is a little harder.

Another option could be to boot into a liveCD and try to copy over some files into another drive or USB. Usually when the kernel has issues, a reinstall will just make things easier.

Comment: I would agree, and I did just that. Problem is the same thing happened again.

Comment: You're getting the same results after installing again? It might be the integrity of you install CD.